# How to replace one string only?

Tags: php, mysql, replace

I have a database and the following string in there:

Test§Test1§Test2§Test3§Test4

Now I have written this piece of code to replace a string in there with a new one:

```
<?php
    $OldName = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_GET['param2']);
    $NewName = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_GET['param3']);
    try {
        $mysqli->query("UPDATE " . $Usr . " SET Categories = REPLACE(Categories, '§" . $OldName . "', '§" . $NewName . "')");
    } catch (Exception $e) {

    }

    try {
        $mysqli->query("UPDATE " . $Usr . " SET Categories = REPLACE(Categories, '" . $OldName . "', '§" . $NewName . "')");
    } catch (Exception $e) {

    }

    try {
        $mysqli->query("UPDATE " . $Usr . " SET Categories = REPLACE(Categories, '§" . $OldName . "', '" . $NewName . "')");
    } catch (Exception $e) {

    }

    try {
        $mysqli->query("UPDATE " . $Usr . " SET Categories = REPLACE(Categories, '" . $OldName . "', '" . $NewName . "')");
    } catch (Exception $e) {

    }
?>
```

This works **BUT** when I try to replace only the first item in the "list" called "Test", then
it replaces every Test in this string, not only the first Test, but I tried to filter that out..

How can I replace JUST the string I would like to replace with the delimiter § in my case?

I hope you understand my Problem..

Comment: You would be better off looking at how to normalize your database so that you have a user/category relationship.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? With 8.0 you can use `REGEX_REPLACE()` to match the keyword preceded and followed either by `§` or the beginning/end of the string.